# angular: how to pass json from array

Tags: angular

I followed [this tutorial](https://masteringionic.com/blog/2019-01-27-creating-a-simple-accordion-widget-in-ionic-4/) , i wanted to display json output instead of a text description. So tried below code but i am getting error `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[ { "productId": 1, "productName": ........ "productPrice": 10000 } ]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

EarningRuleComponent TS file

```
public technologies : Array<{ name: string, description: any, image: string }> = [
{ 
   name : 'Custom event', 
   description : '[ { "productId": 1, "productName": "product 1", "productPrice": 500 }, { "productId": 2, "productName": "product 2", "productPrice": 1000 }, { "productId": 3, "productName": "product 3", "productPrice": 2000 }, { "productId": 4, "productName": "PRODUCT 4", "productPrice": 3000 }, { "productId": 5, "productName": "produt 5", "productPrice": 10000 } ]',
   image: '/assets/images/angular-logo.png'
},
{ 
   name : 'Customer referral', 
   description : '[ { "productId": 1, "productName": "product 1", "productPrice": 500 }, { "productId": 2, "productName": "product 2", "productPrice": 1000 }, { "productId": 3, "productName": "product 3", "productPrice": 2000 }, { "productId": 4, "productName": "PRODUCT 4", "productPrice": 3000 }, { "productId": 5, "productName": "produt 5", "productPrice": 10000 } ]',
    image: '/assets/images/vuejs-logo.png'
}
```

];

EarningRuleComponent HTML file

```
<app-accordion 
   *ngFor="let technology of technologies"
   name="{{ technology.name }}"
   description="{{technology.description}}"
   image="{{ technology.image }}"
   (change)="captureName($event)"></app-accordion> 
</div>
```

MiAccordionComponent TS file

```
@Input()
  description : any;
```

MiAccordionComponent HTML file

```
 <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let resultObj of description">
        {{ resultObj.productName}}
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use **JSON.parse**

In your ts file (**MiAccordionComponent.ts**)

```
public getDescJSON(){
return JSON.parse(description);
}
```

And in your html page (**MiAccordionComponent.html**)

```
     <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let resultObj of getDescJSON()">
    {{ resultObj.productName}}
  </li>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the json pipe like this:

{{ resultObj.productName | json }}